# Redirect all requests but one

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I wonder how to redirect all requests like

```
foobar.com/cat
foobar.com/cat/1
foobar.com/etc
```

to

```
foobar.com/index.php
```

But not to affect

```
foobar.com/webmaster/
```

I don`t want foobar.com/webmaster/ to redirect to index.php. I want it default behavior

How to do that with mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this `foobar.com/(?!webmaster)[\w\/\d\_\-\:\;\?\=\.]+` as your regular expression to match all other except **foobar.com/webmaster/**

Apply this regex to select all except foobar.com/webmaster/ and match with

```
foobar.com/cat
foobar.com/cat/1
foobar.com/etc
```

add replace with

```
foobar.com/index.php
```

Comment: this will not match underscore, which is valid in url

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^webmaster/ - [QSA,L]
RewriteRule .* index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: @What is RewriteEngine which language? I only know regex way to match and replace so I wrote 1 :)

Comment: @Abhishek Simon Question is tagged [`mod-rewrite`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mod-rewrite/info).